# Список созданных мною меток

Tags: обсуждение, метки, data-explorer

Я могу [получить список созданных меток](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/895323/tags-created-by-me?UserId=15479) из таблицы `Posts`, но там нету имени метки.

```
SELECT P.* From Posts AS P
where 
  P.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  AND P.PostTypeId = 4 --TagWikiExcerpt
```

Но когда пытаюсь сджоинить это дело с таблицей меток по `Id`, чтоб имена меток получить, то ничего не выходит. `Id` из таблицы `Tags` - это не те же `Id`, что и в таблице `Posts`.

Как получить список созданных мною меток с их именами?

Comment: I don't speak russian but [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/895332/tags-created-by-me?UserId=15479) is a start. I need to look into the issue that those tags with Cyrillic characters don't correctly get converted into a link. I work on that later. Feel free to hop in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) if I missed anything crucial. *С уважением*

Comment: @rene tnx. You could write it as answer. I will translate it.

Comment: @Suvitruf обещали перевести, а так и не перевели

Comment: @AntonSorokin я в свете действий администрации временно приостановил свою деятельность на SO.

Comment: @AntonSorokin но раз обещал, то переведу.

Comment: @Suvitruf жаль(

Comment: @AntonSorokin перевёл.

Comment: В личном деле будет написано: "Своими действиями и бездействиями разрушает ruSO" :)

Comment: @alexolut "не заходя на сайт, уничтожил его".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Следующий [запрос](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/895332/tags-created-by-me?UserId=15479) создаёт ссылки на искомые wiki страницы меток:

```sql
SELECT concat('site://tags/'
       , t.tagname
       , '/info'
       , '|'
       , t.tagname) as Tag
     , P.creationdate
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
From Posts AS P
inner join tags t on t.excerptpostid = p.id
where 
  P.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##
  AND P.PostTypeId = 4 --TagWikiExcerpt
```

Нету какой-то волшебной ссылки, которая разворачивалась бы в ссылку на wiki метки. И т.к. всё это происходит на клиенте, то нет необходимой информации, чтоб соотнести `Post.Id` с меткой. К счастью, мы можем создать расширение для ссылки.

Вот как всё это работает. Если значение начинается с `site://`, оно будет конвертировано в кликабельную ссылку, где `site://` заменится на DNS имя сайта, для которого вы запускаете запрос. Выбрать сайт сети можно справа в выпадающем меню.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляя `|info text`, ссылка становится более юзерфрендли.

Для этого я создал поле:

> `site://tags/md5/info|md5`

и оно будет преобразовано в SEDE результат как:

> `<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/md5/info">md5</a>`

**Примечание:** в таблице `Posts` вы можете найти текст wiki с `posttypeid = 4`. Оно не содержит инфы о том, что это за метка. Но вы можете это выяснить объединением с таблицей `Tags` по полю `excerptpostid`. Поле `tagname` содержит имя метки.

Есть, правда, баг в регулярке JavaScript, используемой SEDE для парсинга `site://`, из-за которого возникают проблемы с кириллическими символами. Наблюдается также в `Tagnames`, отображаемых SEDE. Об этом было сообщено [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226703/auto-linkification-of-tags-tagname-fails-when-the-tag-name-contains-nonstandard) и было поправлено, но по каким-то причинам было отменено. Я пропинговал Тима, чтобы узнать, каково причина этой регрессии.

Также помните, что SEDE обновляется раз в неделю по субботам.

Почитайте про [схему БД](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), обратите внимание на замечательный [туториал](http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial). Будем рады, если присоединитесь к [SEDE чату](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) (правда, говорим мы только на английском).